# Reattach session back to local display after RDP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a PC that regullary runs an application through the day. This application requires advanced graphical capatibilities and only starts sucessfuly when I'm logged in locally. It also runs correctly when I lock down PC after local sessions.

Sometimes though I need to log in to this computer remotely through RDP. Even when I'm done and disconnect from RDP it seems my Windows session remains connected to some kind of virtual RDP video and said program fails to start on schedule up to until I come home and physically login locally.

Is there any way to make logged in session to reattach back to local PC video after I'm done with RDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open task scheduler, create a new task.

Use your username that you use to log in with for user. (you might want to try 'administrator' if this does not work for your standard user account)

Tick "run whether this user is logged in or not"

Tick highest elevation

New Trigger "At Disconnect from user session"

Choose your user or any user

Tick "remote session" if not ticked.

Action Run Program.

Program: tscon.exe

Arguments: 0 /dest:console

On closing the rdp session this should reattach to the console session.

Comment: Just issuing `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` without creating task is enough as connecting to local console terminates your RDP session.

Comment: @Oleg That's absolutely right, the scheduled task is to make the command automatic each time you finish an rdp session.

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file of this command

```
for /f %%i in ('qwinsta ^| findstr /C:">rdp-tcp#"') do set RDP_SESSION=%%i
:: Strip the >
set RDP_SESSION=%RDP_SESSION:>=%
tscon %RDP_SESSION% /dest:console
```

Comment: And then what?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

There is, but it's not possible with RDP to my knowledge. To do this, install TeamViewer on the host (your PC at home) and then set up a TeamViewer account and setup unattended access. From the client (the remote PC), visit the [TeamViewer Remote Access Web Client](https://login.teamviewer.com/LogOn)

From there, as long as you have flash installed, you can remotely log in to your host, with the best part of this being that it starts a console session rather than a RDP (or remote) session.